# A name for great circles that pass through both poles

Tags: terminology, cartography

The union of two meridians of longitude separated by $180^\circ$ is a great circle. Is there a particular name for these great circles that pass through both poles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term *polar great circle* turns up in both mathematical texts ([*Geometry of Four Dimensions*](http://bit.ly/2jaTTrp); [*Geometry of Lie Groups*](http://bit.ly/2j0Z5AR)) and cartographic sites ([gcmap.com: *Great Circle Mapper*](http://bit.ly/2i6Uj58)).

Other ideas: *vertical circle* (an [astronomical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_circle)); *circle of longitude*.

Comment: I think "polar great circle" sometimes means something like a flight's path from Chicago to Delhi over the Arctic Ocean, although it's not exactly a "polar great circle" in the sense used in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've added two more suggestions.